# Finding percentage of identical classifications month to month

Tags: python, pandas

From a classification algorithm I get a classification for every available combination of date and identifier variable (PERMNO). What I would like to obtain is the percentage of classifications that stays the same in the next month. I.e., if at a certain month t a PERMNO gets classification "1" then I would like to verify if the classification for the PERMNO at month t+1 is the same or not. Here is an example of my data:

```
date        PERMNO  class
1986-01-31  10137   1
1986-02-28  10137   1
1986-03-31  10137   2
1986-04-30  10137   2
1986-05-31  10137   3
2019-07-31  93429   3
2019-08-31  93429   1
2019-09-30  93429   3
2019-10-31  93429   1
2019-11-30  93429   1
```

For this example: for PERMNO = 10137 we have identical classifications to the previous month in the second and fourth row. Lets exclude the first row of a PERMNO because it can never be identical to a previous row since there is now previous row. Therefore, 2/4 = 1/2 receive the same classification as the previous month. For PERMNO = 93429 we have an identical classifications to the previous month in the 10th row. -> 1/4.

Most importantly, I want to find the total percentage that remains the same. In this case: 3/8.

How should I approach this?

**As a sidequestion:** how could I review this per classification label? I.e., "if classification for PERMNO in month t = "1", what percentage of the time will the classification of PERMNO be "1" at time t+1?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the shift operator to compare the data to the previous row on the class column and the permno column to find where the pemno column is the same and the class is the same in the next month. This assumes that the data is always one month apart.

```
((df["class"]==df["class"].shift(1)) & (df["PERMNO"]==df["PERMNO"].shift(1))).sum()
```

output:

`3`

For data that isnt always one month apart, you can convert the date column to datetime

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

then check the year is the same:

```
df["date"].dt.year == df["date"].dt.year.shift(1)
```

and the month is the same:

```
df["date"].dt.month == df["date"].dt.year.month(1)
```

and apply these filters in a similar fashion.

If you want to do some more calculations on each group of PERMNO, try the groupby operator:

Input:

```
PERMNO = dict(list(df.groupby(df["PERMNO"])))
```

Output:

```
{10137:         date  PERMNO  class
 0 1986-01-31   10137      1
 1 1986-02-28   10137      1
 2 1986-03-31   10137      2
 3 1986-04-30   10137      2
 4 1986-05-31   10137      3,
 93429:         date  PERMNO  class
 5 2019-07-31   93429      3
 6 2019-08-31   93429      1
 7 2019-09-30   93429      3
 8 2019-10-31   93429      1
 9 2019-11-30   93429      1}
```